# Points in Pool of Destiny

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

I'm trying to understand how the Pool of Destiny works in Star Wars. In Edge of the Empire page 28 it says

> ...players could theoretically "lock" all the Destiny Points and simply not spend any light side Destiny Points to prevent the GM from using dark side Destiny Points...

This is unclear to me. How are the points locked? When you use a light side point does it become a dark side point and vice versa? Or can you not use one side until you use another? There seems to be some important part of this mechanism that I missed reading and rereading this section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Destiny Points Flip**

The Destiny Pool never grows or shrinks. Only it's makeup changes. So if the players suffer through whatever nastiness the GM throws at them with his starting Destiny, the entire pool will be "light side". If the players don't spend any Destiny Points, they never flip so the GM never gets any back. Thus the pool becomes "locked".

Comment: So when I, as a player, use a light side point it gets converted to a dark side point so the GM can use it for badness?

Comment: @Travis exactly

Comment: @Travis The mechanic is meant to encourage a back and forth in the fortunes of the players. Sometimes things are going well for them. Sometimes they're going really badly.